# Discord-py Move member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot using the Discord-py API and I've ran into a problem I cant get move member to work.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
 async def w(member = discord.Member):
    await bot.say("Password Correct!")
      await move_member(member, 5)
```

I'm getting this error

```
Ignoring exception in command w
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\Test Bot\testbot2.py", line 29, in w
    await move_member(member, 5)
NameError: name 'move_member' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'move_member' is not defined
```

Anyone have a example I can use? Or any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify `bot.move_member`.  You're also doing your arguments wrong.  If you pass the context, then the first argument to your function will be a context object.  The syntax for converters is `argument: Converter`. The signature should be `async def w(ctx, member: discord.Member):`.  Additionally, the second argument to `Client.move_member` must be a `Channel` object.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def move(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.Channel):
    await bot.say("Password Correct!")
    await bot.move_member(member, channel)
```